# Running Java Eclipse SWT (64 Bit Linux)

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, svn, swt

i have a  eclipse project that uses eclipse SWT which runs smoothly on my windows eclipse. i share the project (via SVN) and try to run it on my 64 Bit Linux system. i downloaded a stable swt version for 64 bit linux and imported it into my workspace but i get this error:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles [Unknown Mozilla path (MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME not set)]
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.browser.Mozilla.initMozilla(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.browser.Mozilla.create(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.browser.Browser.<init>(Unknown Source)
at //my project class
```

what can i do about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Unknown Mozilla path (MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME not set)` is hinting at the fact that the WebKit library is missing on your Linux system. If you have a Debian based one (incl. Ubuntu), running the following command should solve your problem:

```
sudo apt-get install libwebkitgtk-1.0-0
```

Comment: it looks like it helped, but now i get this error message: `(SWT:3456): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_window_group_remove_window: assertion 'window->group == window_group' failed`

Comment: Does this [bug report](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=225401) and [this discussion](http://sourceforge.net/p/djproject/discussion/671154/thread/aa9af890) help you?

Comment: If not, you'll probably have to post the relevant code and a larger portion of your stacktrace.

Comment: i opened [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20639049/eclipse-swt-browser-crash-linux-64bit) a while ago, but still gut no answer..