# Eclipse SWT Browser crash (Linux 64Bit)

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, swt

I have a eclipse project that uses the webbrowser from eclipse SWT which runs smoothly on my windows eclipse. I share the project (via SVN) and try to run it on my 64 Bit Linux system. I downloaded a stable swt version for 64 bit linux and imported it into my workspace.

but when i try to start the swt-webbrowser, i get this error:

```
(SWT:2882): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_window_group_remove_window: assertion 'window->group == window_group' failed
```

and the browser doesnt start.

It fits the eclipse-bug-discussion [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=225401) but i dont really understand how I can fix it!

Comment: Are you using SWT and AWT?

Comment: On some linux distros the mozilla xulrunner is no longer installed, but the SWT browser does not work without this, IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and finally came across [this little gem](https://coderwall.com/p/lnf1sq) that explains you can fix it by adding a couple of parameters to your *eclipse.ini* file.

Firstly, ensure that the `xulrunner` package is installed on your system.  Then add the following two lines to *eclipse.ini*:

```
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.XULRunnerPath=/usr/bin/xulrunner
```

If this doesn't work, you can try WebKit by adding this line instead:

```
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.UseWebKitGTK=true
```

Comment: Alas, it seems this no longer works in the new "yyyy-MM" releases, as support for XULRunner appears to have been dropped several years ago.

Comment: Do you know any alternative? I tried your answer, but my eclipse keeps crashing every time I use auto complete. I use openSuse 15.3. The problem happened with the 2022.3 version of eclipse. I even downloaded the 2022.6 and used with a different user, but the problem continues.

Comment: Turns out the problem I was facing on Eclipse was a Suse issue with the libwebkit ([link](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=1111474&goto=1854593&#msg_1854593)). The downgrade resolved the bug.